# Decimal out of range exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, decimal

In my C# application, I am trying to save a decimal price into a SQL Server table. Columns type is `decimal` with no total digits defined.

Without discount calculations, everything works fine.

But when I run some calculations, I get a final value of `21800`, and I get the following error when trying to save it.

```
"Parameter value '218000/00000000000000' is out of range."
```

I don't understand where the extra zeros come from! The only thing I know is with `myValue.ToString()` I get `218000/00000000000000`, too!

I understand that the digits after floating point are caused by the calculations. But whatever they do, my value is `21800` when watching it. Why is it trying to save `218000/00000000000000`? Why does it care at all about the zeros?

Any ideas why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide a code example?

Comment: In the DB you MUST define a decimal precision. Look up what is defined in your table. My guess is that it is something like `decimal(18,14)`

Comment: @lonic I'm afraid not, those discount calculations are done by a whole other classes, but what matters is that the final value is a decimal.

Comment: @juergen I changed my DB column data type to `decimal (19, 4)` and still get the same error. I think I have to also change my `.edmx`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to store decimal numbers:

- **Fixed-Point:** This is what you have defined in your SQL Server project. You defined `decimal (19,4)`, which means 19 digits total and 4 digits after the decimal point. If you define such a type, then **every** number **always** has 4 digits after the decimal point; and also, you cannot store a number with more than 4 digits after the decimal point.  **And note, there is no equivalent to fixed point in C#!**
- **Floating Point:** These are the types `float`, `double` and `decimal` in C#, and the type `float(n)`in SQL Server. In floating point, as the names says, you can basically vary the number of digits before and behind the decimal point. (Technically, you have a fixed number of digits, the so-called mantissa, and you can then move the decimal point around with a 2nd number, the exponent)

**So now to your project:** In your database, you use **fixed point**, while in C#, you have **floating point**. Therefore, when you calculate something in C#, and you want to store in to your database, then it is always converted from floating point to fixed point. However, if your number in C# does not fit the decimal numbers in the database, then you get the out of range error.

Comment: But my SQL column type was `Decimal` first, not `decimal (19, 4)`. I suppose it wasn't fixed point then!

Comment: @Yalda `decimal` without parameters is default to `decimal(18,0)`.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I had to specify the total digits of my decimal column in the SQL table (I set it as `decimal (19, 4)`).

Besides, my C# representing field also needed to have the right precision count.

I still don't know about the extra zeros and why SQL care about them. Any explanations is appreciated.